# How to use JavaScript to get form data, and add it to a list

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, custom-list

Obviously it is possible to gather data from a form using JavaScript. Microsoft also claims that is possible to add items to a custom list using JavaScript, although I have not gotten that to work. My thinking is that I could collect form data from a public facing website using a couple of JavaScript functions then add it to a custom list.

Since I am new to Sharepoint, I have not gotten Javascript functions that are in my html code to execute properly. Are there any hoops I have to jump through first?

And also is there anything that would prevent me from gathering data, and putting it into a Sharepoint custom list using JavaScript? Permissions mainly I would guess.

This is my first go around with a Sharepoint website, so it might be a little too ambitious.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you can do CRUD operations using SPServices

e.g - Create Items

```
function CreateNewItem() {
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    batchCmd: "New",
    listName: "Objectives",
    valuepairs: [["Title", "YourTitle"], ["Message=", "Message Text"]],
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
      alert("done");
    }
});}
```

Reference Link for SPServices
https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/245285

CRUD operations through javascript client object model

To create list items, you create a ListItemCreationInformation object, set its properties

e.g. - Create Items

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";
oListItem["Message"] = "Hello World!";
oListItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Referenced MSDN links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011%28v=office.14%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976%28v=office.14%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185009%28v=office.14%29.aspx

hope it helps

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, if the link breaks it will be of little help to future readers as it's written now.

Comment: i think this is trusted links... so i put here,
if other links, i definately provide details with links

Comment: Still it is better to provide details along with links.

Comment: okay i will update my answer with details soon... thanks nadeem

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: What must you use for the site URL? I have tried a number of things but cannot get the above code to work.